# How to proceed with building an ensemble classifier using Naive Bayes, TAN and Logistic Regression in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, ensemble-learning

I'm relatively new to machine learning (started about 5 months ago), and I'm looking at potentially implementing an ensemble classifier as part of my research.

I have built 3 models that I use to classify whether sales data is going to win or lose. Each model produces the probability of the sale winning or losing, and then I apply thresholds to those to classify them as either a "Win", "Loss" or "Borderline Loss". There are 25 variables, all of which are discrete.

The three models are Naive Bayes, Tree Augmented Naive Bayes (TAN) and Logistic Regression. I am using the bnlearn package for the bayesian classifiers, and a simple glm for the Logistic Regression. All models have high accuracy performances when tested on unseen data:

Naive Bayes Accuracy: 88%

TAN Accuracy: 91%

Logistic Regression Accuracy: 92%

I want to try implementing an ensemble classifier to see if I can get the best possible accuracy across all three models. My question is, how do I go about implementing something like this? I can't find too many examples online, at least not with these models for implementing one. From what I have read, one way to do it is to have a voting system, where if the 2 models predict the sale will win, but 1 predicts with will lose, then it is classified as a win. But what happens in this case if all 3 models had different predictions? I have all my prediction data ready, as in I have all the test data and each models prediction for each sale, my question so is, how would I proceed from here?

If someone knows of any available resources or tutorials that may help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What does TAN mean?

Comment: Tree Augmented Naive Bayes. Sorry I'll edit the post to make that clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're discarding information by taking continuous predictions and making them into categories. I would strongly advise against taking that path. Instead, you could (1) average or (2) stack the models. Averaging is straightfoward and requires no additional tuning; on the other hand, all models are weighted equally which might be suboptimal. Stacking adds another layer of learning to train the model on the model outputs against unseen data outcomes.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by discarding information? All the variables I am using are categorical and discrete. I don't see how making them into categories would discard information on them? 

By averaging, do you mean averaging the actual accuracies? Or averaging the predictions of each individual sale opportunity?

Comment: Instead of knowing $p(\text{win}),$ the categories only tell you if $p(\text{win})>c$ where $c$ is your threshold. The *degree* of correctness is important, because it captures the difference between 0.9 and 0.51. If c=0.5, then both are treated the same.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean. For example take the Naive Bayes classifier. I can get the associated probabilities of Win and Lose for each opportunity. So I then take that probability and apply my thresholds to them like so `predictions <- ifelse(naiveprob$Won >= .8, "WIN", ifelse(naiveprob$Won >=.4, "BORDERLINE LOSS", "LOSS"))
`. The reason I have to do this is because at my job they have a fourth model which categorizes each opportunity into those 3 categories, and I do the same so they are easily comparable, and I can say that my new model performs better than their current one

Comment: My overall goal would be to try and generate an ensemble classifier of the 3 models I have built, and then be able to compare the results of that ensemble to the already existing model my workplace uses. That is why I need to categorize the results into 3 categories

Comment: Yeah, I understand what thresholding means. My point is that it's poor practice because it pretends that 0.81 and 0.99 are the same (both are "wins") even though the difference between 0.81 and 0.99 is sizable. This is an improper scoring rule, and will usually pick the wrong model. This paper provides some more context on why accuracy isn't great http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shavlik/roc.pdf It's better to use a proper scoring rule like Brier score, log-loss, c-statistic, etc depending on what your goal is. If your firm is committed to this procedure, though... who cares what best practice is...

Comment: Ah ok I see where you are coming from now. You see the work I am doing is built on previous research conducted at my work place, and through their research, these were the threshold they identified as being the best to use given the application of it to sales forecasting. That paper looks interesting though, I'll be sure to give it a read as part of research. For your suggestions, how exactly does averaging work? Does it average the probabilities for each opportunity across each model?

Comment: Yes, that's how ensemble averaging works.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, I'll give that a shot as a way to get started anyways. Thanks for your help, as well the criticisms!

Comment: Glad to help. If this has been helpful, please consider upvoting (and/or accepting) my answer. But if you'd like to hold off on accepting for 1-2 days, it might encourage others to provide input as well. So waiting would make sense in that case. It's all up to you, no pressure, I just like to help new users navigate the site.